# Exception on OnNavigatedTo when returning to the app

Tags: windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross 3.5.1 with Windows Phone 8 Silverlight. The app is using using background execution:

```
  <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="Views/MainPage.xaml" >
      <BackgroundExecution>
        <ExecutionType  Name="Location" />
      </BackgroundExecution>
  </DefaultTask>
```

If I open the app, click start, and then open the app again I'm getting the exception on MvxPhonePage.OnNavigatedTo method with message:

> Unable to find incoming MvxViewModelRequest

I've noticed that page is created 2 times and the exception is only thrown the second time and NavigationEventArgs.Uri contains only "/Views/FirstView.xaml" unlike the first time when it contains mvvmcross's paramteters.

Also I created project without MvvmCross. Page constructor is invoked only once, and OnNavigateTo twice.

Call stack:

```
Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.DLL!Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneViewsContainer.GetRequestFromXamlUri(System.Uri viewUri)  Unknown
Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.DLL!Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneExtensionMethods.LoadViewModel(Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.IMvxPhoneView phoneView, System.Uri navigationUri, Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedStateBundle)    Unknown
Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.DLL!Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate.AnonymousMethod__0()    Unknown
Cirrious.MvvmCross.DLL!Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Views.IMvxView view, System.Func<Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel> viewModelLoader)  Unknown
Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.DLL!Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhoneExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate(Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.IMvxPhoneView phoneView, System.Uri navigationUri, Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedStateBundle) Unknown
Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.DLL!Cirrious.MvvmCross.WindowsPhone.Views.MvxPhonePage.OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)   Unknown
Phone8Native.DLL!Phone8Native.Views.FirstView.OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) Line 16    C#
Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) Unknown
Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.Microsoft.Phone.Controls.IPhoneApplicationPage.InternalOnNavigatedToX(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) Unknown
Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.RaiseNavigated(object content, System.Uri uri, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode mode, bool isNavigationInitiator, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.IPhoneApplicationPage existingContentPage, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.IPhoneApplicationPage newContentPage) Unknown
Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.CompleteNavigation(System.Windows.DependencyObject content, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode mode)   Unknown
Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(System.IAsyncResult result) Unknown
Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(System.AsyncCallback userCallback, System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result) Unknown
Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll!System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad.AnonymousMethod__0(object args)    Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.ni.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority)    Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(object context)  Unknown
System.Windows.ni.dll!System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(object[] args)   Unknown
System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll!System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(System.IntPtr pHandle, int nParamCount, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pParams, System.Windows.Hosting.NativeMethods.ScriptParam* pResult)   Unknown
```

Comment: Can you provide a full stack trace?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I added call stack and additional info.